# Date Function Not Working?

Tags: php, mysql, function, date

I am trying to set the date that a channel has been created for my website, with MySQL and PHP.

The MySQL code is:

```
$date = date("d-m-Y");

$create_channel = mysql_query("INSERT INTO channels VALUES ('','$channel_name','$user','$date')");
```

The variables are all set, however in the MySQL database the date is showing as:
00-00-0000

Any ideas why?

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You you should use `mysqli_*`or `PDO`.

Comment: I know, this is more so for learning purposes.

Comment: Learn about the format that MySQL expects for its date values: clue, it isn't `d-m-Y`

Comment: `I know, this is more so for learning purposes.` Why not learn the correct way from the off?

Comment: Mark Baker was giving you a clue. Y-m-d is the format MySQL needs. Brice is right too. Don't use mysql_* functions because they are deprecated in the newer PHP versions and surely will be removed in the near future. Those zero values in your date column of your table is because MySQL isn't strict by default which is a stupid behaviour. It should throw an error,  but that's not part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and learn something from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php